# Prevent the 'Ding' sound when clicking on a disabled windows form

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I have a winform Application written in C#. This application should show Notifications on the Desktop that are non-interactable and should not gain focus. Now I've figured out how to spawn windows in the background (behind all other applications) and make them non-interactable.
Despite them being disabled, every time I click on one, the Windows "DING" sound plays.

Is there a way to have a form `Enabled = false;` without it giving the ding sound when trying to click on it?

Instead of having the form disabled, I also try to capture all the click events and prevent the focusing, but this has not worked so far.

Below is the code I used for creating the windows form.

```cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Background_Notes;

public partial class Note : Form
{
    
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

    static readonly IntPtr HwndBottom = new IntPtr(1);
    const UInt32 SwpNosize = 0x0001;
    const UInt32 SwpNomove = 0x0002;
    const UInt32 SwpNoactivate = 0x0010;
    
    public Note()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ShowInTaskbar = false;
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);

        TextBox t = new TextBox();
        t.Width = 200;
        t.Text = "This is a notification!";
        Controls.Add(t);
        
        Show();
        SetWindowPos(Handle, HwndBottom, 0, 0, 0, 0, SwpNomove | SwpNosize | SwpNoactivate);
        Enabled = false;
    }
    

    protected override bool ShowWithoutActivation => true;
}
```

Comment: Intercept the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-mouseactivate event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the window always inactive, apply WS_EX_NOACTIVATE to the [extended window style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles).There is no need to disable the form.

```cs
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            if (DesignMode)
                return cp;

            const int WS_EX_NOACTIVATE = 0x8000000;
            cp.ExStyle |= WS_EX_NOACTIVATE;
            return cp;
        }
    }
```